# Pulling data from server and appending to list without duplicating list

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good Day!. I have been using get requests via jquery to  pull data from flask server and appending it to a list on my html. However i have to remove list before appending a new list or else it will add the same values to the list. Is there a way to check a list of values and if any new values found in list, only add that value. Thanks. Here's my code.

```
function message(){
 $('#message_ol').children().remove()  ###Here i have to remove the list before add to it.
 $.getJSON('/message',
 function(data){
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    if (data[i].verb == 'yes'){
      var snd = new Audio("static/img/beep.mp3");
      snd.play();
      snd.currentTime=0;
    }
    $('#message_ol').append("<li>"+ data[i].message +"</li>")
  }
})
}


###If i dont remove the  list then this happens. Every 5 seconds jquery pulls the data from the server
1. Message 1
2. Message 2
###5 seconds
3. Message 1
4. Message 2
5. Message 3
###Same values added plus new ones
```

Comment: Why don't you loop through your previously generated list to check whether any existing values matches with the data from your api.. If yes skip that value else append to tour list

Comment: Do you have a unique identifier to determine duplicates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not test this but here is the basic idea... assuming as @Steve0 indicated.... you want to make sure you have a unique identifier in your JSON response to be sure the data was not already added to the list.

```
function message(){
//  $('#message_ol').children().remove()  ###Here i have to remove the list before add to it.
$.getJSON('/message', function(data){
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){

        if (data[i].verb == 'yes'){
            var snd = new Audio("static/img/beep.mp3");
            snd.play();
            snd.currentTime=0;
        }

        if($("#message_ol>li[data-message='" + data[i] + "']").length === 0){
            $('#message_ol').append('<li data-message="'+data[i]+'">' + data[i].message +'</li>')
        }
    }
})
```

}

Comment: I recommend changing your if condition to `$("#message_ol>li[data-message='" + data[i] + "']").length ===0` at the least you need to put square brackets around your attribute selector

Comment: Steve0 ... true... thx.. i quickly typed that... u are correct

Comment: this worked. the only thing i had to  add was .message to data[i], but other than that it works. thanks!

Comment: Another thing. If i were to check a database for values and compare it to list, and the database values get deleted, how can i then delete or remove the list values.